# Check if application is up in the maven pre-integration-test phase?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin, exec-maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

I am making my application up in the pre-integration-test phase and then the integration test cases run using the failsafe plugin.
I want to ensure that my application is up and running in the pre-integration-test phase before the integration test cases are executed.

I got two probable ways to achieve this :

1. **Maven-antrun-plugin**

```
<waitfor maxwait="100" maxwaitunit="second" checkevery="500">
    <http url="https://localhost/myapp/index.html"/>
</waitfor>
```

2. **exec-maven-plugin**

```
            
          <execution>
            <id>wait</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <executable>sleep</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>100</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this OR any other maven plugin to achieve the same functionality ?

Comment: If this really a spring boot application? If so I would recommend to use testcontainers or use the methods to test via Spring Boot itself...the question what kind of test you are trying to run?

Comment: @khmarbaise  - These are integration test cases which test the complete end to end business logic like uploading the file , validating it and other business logic stuff. And yes its a module inside a spring boot application.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of IT you are writing? Because a single startup does not make sense because if you start the app you have one instance with a single port being used. That can not run on a CI/CD solution with multiple branches...If you really need to startup your application within an IT it sounds more like an system integration test...for such purposes testcontainers is a better solution... I would never use Maven for such things...